# How to recover a gitlab repository from a git bundle?

Tags: git, gitlab, backup, restore

By accident, I forcefully pushed from my local repository to the GitLab repository having mirroring active which then deleted all the hidden and GitLab related refs (for the merge request 'refs/merge-request') in the remote.

I told my coworkers to stop interacting with the remote repository and asked OPs if I could get the daily backup for that repository. I received a `repositoryname.bundle` file.

Now how can I recover the remote with this bundle file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it on my own like this.

Create a temporary directory and cd there

```
cd $(mktemp -d)
```

Get the bundle from your OPs (full snapshot) of the repository there

```
mv /tmp/yourrepo.bundle .
```

Clone the broken repository from GitLab to BROKEN

```
git clone --mirror URL_to_yourrepo BROKEN.git
```

cd in BROKEN and run git bundle verify ../reponame.bundle. It should not report any errors, if so, continue

```
cd BROKEN.git
git bundle verify ../yourrepo.bundle
```

Go back and then clone a new repository from the bundle file

```
cd ..
cd git clone --mirror yourrepo.bundle LASTKNOWNGOOD.git
```

cd there and verify that all your refs are there as u expect them to be

```
cd LASTKNOWNGOOD.git
git show-ref
```

Now set the repositories remote to the local BROKEN clone from GitLab

```
git remote add BROKEN ../BROKEN.git
```

Then push the contents of here to the BROKEN remote

```
git push --tags --force --mirror BROKEN
```

By then, the BROKEN repository should be healed.
cd into the BROKEN and simulate a push to verify that it will do what you expect

```
cd ../BROKEN.git
git push --tags --verbose --dry-run --mirror origin
```

If it looks like u expect it to be, run without `--dry-run` to heal the remote repository.
It may report about `remote rejected` but as long as they are from the `keep-around` refs group you can safely ignore them.
You also need to reopen all the automatically closed merge request in GitLab for that repository.